# custom checkbox difficulty in android

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox, adapter

how to modify this imageCheckBoxAdapter code in order to maintain status of checkBox when scrolled(that is all the checkboxes which are checked should remain checked even after scrolling. Also the checked variables need to be stored in an array)?

```
class imageCheckBoxAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
private final Context context;
private final ArrayList<String> values;
private final Map< String, SmbFile> obj;
static ArrayList<Boolean> checks=new ArrayList<Boolean>();
public imageCheckBoxAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> values,Map< String, SmbFile>obj) 
{
    super(context, R.layout.row_checkbox, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
    this.obj=obj;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_checkbox, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text1_check);
    textView.setText(values.get(position));
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon_image_check);
    try
    {
        if((obj.get(values.get(position)).isFile()))
        {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.view_file_icon);
        }
        else
        {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.view_folder_icon);
        }
    }
    catch (SmbException e) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Network error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("id1", "error1");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rowView;
}
}
```

row_checkbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >
    <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="false" />
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon_image_check"
    android:layout_width="50px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
    android:layout_marginRight="20px"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
    android:src="@drawable/view_file_icon" >
    </ImageView>
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1_check"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="30px" 
    android:typeface="sans">
    </TextView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class imageCheckBoxAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements View.onClickListener
{
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<String> values;
    private final Map< String, SmbFile> obj;
    private ArrayList<Boolean> checks=new ArrayList<Boolean>();

    public imageCheckBoxAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> values,Map< String, SmbFile>obj) 
    {
        super(context, R.layout.row_checkbox, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
        this.obj=obj;

        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
            checks.add(i, false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_checkbox, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text1_check);
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        textView.setText(values.get(position));
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon_image_check);
        try
        {
            if((obj.get(values.get(position)).isFile()))
            {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.view_file_icon);
            }
            else
            {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.view_folder_icon);
            }
        }
        catch (SmbException e) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Network error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("id1", "error1");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        chk.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));

        // Set a listener for the checkbox
        chk.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Sets the state of CB, since we have the list of checked CB
        chk.setChecked(checks.get(position));

        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Integer index = (Integer)view.getTag();
        boolean state = checks.get(index.intValue());

        checks.set(index.intValue(), !state);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,whats the use of 'state' variable in this code?                    @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
     Integer index = (Integer)view.getTag();
     boolean state = checks.get(index.intValue());

     checks.set(index.intValue(), true);
   }

Comment: and when i try to read 'checks' static variable from outside, it throws error ..why?

Comment: don't access the checks try to have an getter method for the list of checks values and i edit my code above.

Answer (score 0):

I think your need to store value in an array. For each checkBox, you set a changeListener to store the checkBox associated.

Comment: on my suggestion above it is better to choose onClickListener than onCheckedChangedListener because in getView we set the state of checkbox, since we set the state the of the checkBox, onCheckedChange method will be called since our code use to save the state of the checkbox by using arraylist.

When the listview is scrolled the result will be contaminated of because the state of the checkbox will be changed again

Answer (score 0):

I recently read, not sure where already, a similar case someone asked about.

If I understand correctly, this may be because the `CheckBox` control is not databound in the `DataRepeaterItem`, and when scrolling the checkboxes lose their state.

You can try using `Viewstate` to maintain checked value. I'll try finding that post, it seemed informative.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can save the position of the checkbox in the list by using the View.setTag method
make a reference of your checkbox in the getView like this:

```
CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
```

Since CheckBoxes are indirect subclasses of View, it also has an attribute View.setTag like this:

```
chk.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
```

Then set an OnCheckedChangeListener to your chk like:

```
chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean state) {
           Integer int = (Integer)buttonView.getTag();

           checks.set(int.intValue(), !boolean)
    }
});
```

Since the boolean arraylist size is same to the values size, the specified position corresponds the exact location of the checkbox

Then add this snippet to your getView method:

```
if (checks.get(position)) {
  chk.setChecked(checks.get(position));
  // do some stuff if wanted..
} else {
  chk.setChecked(checks.get(position));
  // do some stuff if wanted..
}
```

We did the snippet because when listview is scrolled upward or downward getView is called for the unseen row item. And to update the row item if already checked or not.

Comment: HI, joey since i am new to android programming, i am finding it difficult to add your code to my code snippet. So can u please edit my code and do changes?

Comment: hi, i cannot able to ask questions. they have prevented me from asking questions so i have used meta stack overflow to ask my question. please go through my question and answer it..please quickly send ur response. its urgent for my project