# Android - Filtering a listview

Tags: android, filter, android-arrayadapter

I want to implement the following:

Listview 1 contains items with checkboxes. If one or more items are checked, listview 2 should only show items that contain the checked items.

What would be the best way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question about how to implement checkboxes in each listview element. It could be tricky since the adapter refreshes the states of each checkbox on scrolling. Check David Scott's answer and my comments on it for proper use. Also check out Joey's answer after that.

[ListView adapter with many checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298387/listview-adapter-with-many-checkboxes)

Regarding your 2nd listview you will have to check your boolean array which rows are checked. Then get all elements at those indexes from your collection and save them. Either you:

- Use all the element rows that was checked(in some container class) and set these to your listview adapter number 1. Then use adapter.notifySetDataChanged() and these will appear.
- If you want to keep your listview number 1, create a new activity with the 2nd listview, pass the chosen objects to it and use them as elements. Or simply put a listview below the 2nd one with the checked rows.

Dont know how much you know about listviews but this are my 50 cents about the topic.