# How to check a checkbox if it is checked prevoiusly

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I have implemented check box in a list, there is a names with check box. My problem is, I will select five names and I will display those names, after that if I come back to list, again those five names should be checked because I have already selected those names.

But now those are **unchecked** when I have revisited. How to achieve this.

**My adapter code.**

```
     holder.UserId_Fk.setText(tempValues.getUserId_Fk().toString());
            holder.chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

            holder.chkbox.setChecked(checkedHolder[position]);
            Log.i(TAG, "Position " + checkedHolder[position]);

            if (checkedHolder[position])
                holder.chkbox.setChecked(true);
            else
                holder.chkbox.setChecked(false);

            holder.chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                boolean isChecked) {

                            checkedHolder[position] = isChecked;
                            Log.i(TAG, "Position " + checkedHolder[position]);
                        }
                    });
```

**My activity code..**

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkbox);

                cb.performClick();

                if (cb.isChecked()) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                        if (adapter.checkedHolder[i]) {
                            // get all name values that checked by user
                            MemberName.clear();
                            MemberName.add(ItemsArr.get(i).getItemName().toString());
                            cb.setChecked(true);
                            Log.i(TAG, "Name " + MemberName);
                            // Name = ItemsArr.get(i).getItemName().toString();
                            //Log.i(TAG, "Name " + Name);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (!cb.isChecked()) {

                }    
            }    
        });
```

Comment: you could use a map Map<Integer, Boolean> and when calls the method go to " re-select " the checkboxes that were selected, so if boolean for integer position is true set checkbox to true.

Comment: You'll have to save their positions.

Comment: You shouldn't really be asking if your code can be edited for you, for all we know this could be a homework question. You should be asking for examples that illustrate the concept or links to helpful pages.

You'll not learn if someone simply edits your code and you just accept it as working, but don't know why it's working.

In this instance I'd recommend looking for topics on scope and persistence.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you store the state somewhere, every time you go back to the list it will be treated like a new instance. As a result all boxes will go back to being unchecked.

When you go away from the list, save the checked values to some sort of persistent storage, like device storage, or pass the state of the boxes to the screen you're going to so that it can be passed back to the list when navigating back. Alternatively save them to a variable that has global scope and won't fall out of scope when moving screens.

When you go back to the list, see if there's a state to be used (either in the device storage, passed in as a parameter, or whatever means of persistence you use) then use it to re-check the appropriate boxes.

Comment: How to save can u guide me

Comment: I've mentioned three methods. The easiest is probably global scoping. When you are about to navigate away, grab the checked status of each checkbox and store it in a List<boolean>, Map<int,boolean> or other collection variable.

Not knowing the exact structure of your program i can't say where to put this collection, but it has to be somewhere that the list has access to, and doesn't end or fall out of use by the time you come back to the list.

Comment: Yes, @ForceGaia is right you need to save the state of the checkbox so that you can get the states back. You can check this link pal :) [custom checkbox difficulty in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214271/custom-checkbox-difficulty-in-android/10278905#10278905)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have edit your code

```
 private static Map<Integer, Boolean> mapCheck = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
     holder.UserId_Fk.setText(tempValues.getUserId_Fk().toString());
        holder.chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        holder.chkbox.setChecked(checkedHolder[position]);
        Log.i(TAG, "Position " + checkedHolder[position]);

        if (checkedHolder[position])
            holder.chkbox.setChecked(true);
        else
            holder.chkbox.setChecked(false);

        holder.chkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
            mapCheck.put(position, true);
                        checkedHolder[position] = isChecked;
                        Log.i(TAG, "Position " + checkedHolder[position]);
                    }
                });
```

And this:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chkbox);

            cb.performClick();

            if (cb.isChecked()) {
        /*
                for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    if (adapter.checkedHolder[i]) {
                        // get all name values that checked by user
                        MemberName.clear();
                        MemberName.add(ItemsArr.get(i).getItemName().toString());
                        cb.setChecked(true);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Name " + MemberName);
                        // Name = ItemsArr.get(i).getItemName().toString();
                        //Log.i(TAG, "Name " + Name);
                    } */

          //SEARCH POSITION WHERE ARE TRUE
           for(Integer i : mapCheck.keySet())
            {
          if(mapCheck.get(i) == true)
           {
             cb.setChecked(true);
           }
          }
                }
            } else if (!cb.isChecked()) {

            }

        }

    });
```

Comment: @Simon there is some mistake ?